Aquatic monster movie
I saw this film either in the late 90's or the early 2000's. It was definitely a horror movie (and a bad one too). I remember a group of teenagers on a cruise boat and there was an aquatic monster (or aquatic monsters) that was (were) infectious. My adolescent self was particularly impressed with a sex scene between an infected boy and a girl and afterwards the girl was infected too.
More details: there was a bonfire scene towards the beginning of the film. In the aforementioned sex scene, I think the insinuation was that the intercourse passed on the infection. Infected people eventually vomited and became deformed.
Edit: The creature(s) was(ere) visible. I didn't intend to be vague but I was young. The film was likely from the 90s or late 80s. I use Stack exchange before, just not the movie site until yesterday. Please tell me how to be proper rather than downvoting.

So is that the age of the film or was it older? And it's definitely a visible creature, not a virus\parasite?

If it's late 80s, it could be Uninvited about an infectious cat monster on a yacht. But I don't recall the particular scene you mentioned.

Thank you Walt! I will verify whether Uninvited is the one.

@ Walt: Uninvited is not the one. But skimming through it made me remember a few more details.

Uninvited is not related to The Uninvited, which was originally released in the 40's (I think) and was remade a few years ago.

Okay, if you're after a clunker, it could very well be this one... Plankton (AKA Creatures From The Abyss), a B-movie from 1994. From IMDb:

Five teenagers embark on a boating trip off the coast of Florida. The teens get hopelessly lost at sea after they get caught in a fierce storm. Fortunately, the quintet stumble across an abandoned yacht in the middle of the ocean with a mysterious biology lab on board it. Unfortunately, there are also ferocious mutated prehistoric fish running amok on the yacht. Will any of the teens survive this harrowing ordeal? 

A monster fish infects one of the boys who mutates, but not before he has sex with a girl and infects her with a mutant fish baby. You can find pictures of the fish as well as a colorful recap at badmovies.org. Here's the trailer:




Thank you so much. I know it's a bad movie but not being able to remember it has bothered me for years! I'll upvote you when I have enough rep.
